# Could not build wheels for pyscipopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, scip, pyscipopt

when installing a module for python, pyscipopt throws an error:
Collecting pyscipopt
Using cached PySCIPOpt-4.3.0.tar.gz (665 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
Building wheel for pyscipopt (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pyscipopt (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [38 lines of output]
Assuming that SCIP is installed globally, because SCIPOPTDIR is undefined.

```
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\cutsel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\reader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\pyscipopt
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
  scip.c
  src\pyscipopt\scip.c(772): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: scip/scip.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscipopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Collecting pyscipopt
Using cached PySCIPOpt-4.3.0.tar.gz (665 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
Building wheel for pyscipopt (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pyscipopt (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [38 lines of output]
Assuming that SCIP is installed globally, because SCIPOPTDIR is undefined.

```
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\cutsel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\reader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\pyscipopt
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
  scip.c
  src\pyscipopt\scip.c(772): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: scip/scip.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscipopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states that scip.h could not be found, so you need to install the SCIP Optimization Suite before installing PySCIPOpt.

It's best to just use the conda installer because that contains all dependencies.